# How to aggregate two numerical variables then calculate the ratio

Tags: r

I have a dataset as below with five columns:**Date, WeekNum, Year,Total Hours, Total Production**

I want to sum my Total Hours by weeknum and year, also sum total production by weeknum and year, then use the first sum divided by second sum.

I know I can use aggregate function, for example:

```
sum1<-aggregate(list(TotalHours=input$TotalHours), by = list(Year=input$Year, WeekNum=input$WeekNum), FUN=sum)

sum2<-aggregate(list(TotalProduction=input$TotalProduction), by = list(Year=input$Year, WeekNum=input$WeekNum), FUN=sum)
```

then use sum1/sum2

However if there any easy way to simply this code or there is another function can help me to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Start with pasting the result of `dput(input)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`, pass your weeknum and year variables into `group_by`, after that pass your TotalProduction and TotalHours to the `summarise`, just like I did with mpg and wt variables, and finally use `mutate` to compute new variable finalsum on top of variables which you computed in the summarise step. Here is an example code based on mtcars:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, carb) %>%
  summarise(sum_mpg=sum(mpg), sum_wt=sum(wt)) %>%
  mutate(finalsum = sum_mpg/sum_wt)
```

Comment: dplyr approach has more elegant syntax (one does not have to use data$variable, just use the variable name), and it is faster, especially when it comes to larger data. I have simulated this two approaches on 8 million records data, and dplyr code had the job done in half a second, while aggregate approach was running 52 seconds in order to throw results. So when working with bigger datasets I would highly recommend switching to dplyr.

Comment: Thank you so much!